# Newtons Cooling Law estimate constant

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, linear-approximation

Newton's law of cooling states that $\frac{dT}{dt}= -k(T-T_s)$ if $T(0)=100$, $T(3)=75$ and $T_s=25$ then how would you use linear approximation to estimate the value of k?

Can you use the Mean Value Theorem which tells you that at a point c $\in  (0,3)$ the slope of the tangent is $\frac{-25}{3}$ ?

Comment: Possible hint/strategy I haven't tried. The solution to the differential equation is an exponential function. Write it down, then expand in a power series and look at the first term.

Comment: what about without solving the differential equation?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to answer the question - it depends on a little bit of not quite common knowledge and may not count as linear approximation.

You know the "$1/3$ life" of the cooling process is $3$ seconds. That's how long it takes to get $1/3$ of the way from $100$ to $25$.

That means
$$
e^{3k} = 1/3
$$
so
$$
3k = -\ln 3 \approx -1.1
$$
and
$$
k \approx -1.1/3 \approx -0.37.
$$

The not quite common knowledge is the value of 
$$ \ln 3  = 1.0986\ldots \approx 1.1 .
$$
(More people know $\ln 2 \approx 0.7$, which leads to the "[rule of $70$](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1&ei=dr8UWqjFAsKX_Qbf76eICg&q=rule%20of%2070&oq=rule%20of%2070&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i131k1j0l9.206709.209292.0.209610.10.7.0.3.3.0.149.624.6j1.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.10.637...35i39k1j0i67k1j0i20i264k1j0i3k1j0i131i20i264k1.0.hMH3_mFOBJg)" for doubling time when compounding interest. This approximation tells you the "rule of $110$" for tripling.)

Comment: you have to use linear approximation